# Need webcam presentation software for digital projectors

Tags: software

I am about to do a presentation of a mobile application at a conference. I have a good USB webcam to use, so I can point at the phone, but want to put it through my laptop and then through a projector for the audience to see. Can anyone recommend a simple a decent software package, (that is free to) ? Has to be compatible with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a mac user, so haven't tried these out, but:

http://camdesk.sourceforge.net/ looks lightweight and may do the trick

http://www.screenmonkey.co.uk/ is more comprehensive live-presentation software, but should be able to get a webcam video-source full screen.